# Translation-Strings only translated when debug once set to 1 while rendered

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

Since its the second Cake-Project where this mystery appears now I need to know whats the cause:

When I add new translations to any of the `.po-files` and want it to be translated in the view, it's not. Until it got once rendered while Core-Config's debug-value was set to 1 or 2. After that it's all fine going with debug-value set to 0.

Due to this behavior I suspect the cache.

It seems to work on the local windows machine as suggested, not so on the Debian. The directory-rights are set to `777`.

Additional: This is not taking place since the start of the project but a few days ago, without me being able to intend why or what has been changed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, clear the cache after you changed your translations - in debug mode this will be done automatically from time to time (every x seconds).

Comment: Thanks. That brought be to disable cache: Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);